# Angular library 404 loading.gif not found

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular13

I currently have monorepo which contains a standard Angular application. At the same level as my app, I have an Angular workspace which contains only a library.

I did the necessary mapping in the main app to tell it where my library is. I can use the components of my lib without any problem.

I have a component called "loader" that uses a gif image that is in my assets folder. At the time of the build of the application I see that my images are well exported in the build folder but when I open the browser I receive a 404 error that it does not find my gif.

---

`projects/my-lib-name/: ng-package.json`

```json
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/hive-commons",
  "assets": ["./assets"],
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts"
  }
}
```

`projects/my-lib-name/src/lib/my-module/my-folder-component: my-component.html`

```html
<img src="assets/hive-commons/img/loading.gif" alt="Loading"/>
```

Inside `workspace-name/dist/my-lib-name/assets/img` I can see my `loading.gif` but when I import this component in my apps I got this `404 loading.gif not found` ->
`http://localhost:4200/assets/hive-commons/img/hive-loading-70.gif`

Comment: Open Chrome dev tools, look at the `<head>` element and search the `<base href="...">` inside it. What is its value ? Also, can you try `<img src="./assets/hive-commons/img/loading.gif" alt="Loading"/>`

Comment: Here the value: `<base href="/">` 
Already try the `<img src="./assets/....`

The problem I can see now, is that my library try to reach this image inside the `assets` folder, as I import my lib inside an app it trying to fetch inside the app assets and ofc it won't find there... I can't figure out how can I map from my app angular

Comment: There is a way to take assets in node_modules and re-map it somewhere else. I am writing as an answer as I lack place here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `angular.json`, you can extract assets from your lib and re-expose them in your project. Syntax is :

```
"assets": [
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "node_modules/my-dependency/assets",
    "output": "./my-dependency-assets/"
  },
```

Of course, you can decide to expose them in `./assets` instead of `./my-dependency-assets` but I would not mix the app assets with the library assets as it will be a headache in case of homonym assets.

For example, in hive-commons you can rename the assets folder to `hive-assets` to that all your library components point to assets urls such as `./hive-assets/path/to/image.png`.

Then, in your main app, you remap `dist/hive-commons/hive-assets` to `hive-assets`

Comment: I'll try it and come back to you

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It work like a charm :) And I will follow your advice about the assets folder name.